# How to differ between MSSQL JDBC error codes?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

My server calls sometimes the MSSQL JDBC `CallableStatement.execute()` that works with a previously connected connection. Everything is ok while the connection is alive. But if the connection is disconnected somehow (e.g. somebody turn SQL server down) the `execute()` call throws `SQLException`. I need to differ between 'connection was dropped' error and any other JDBC error (like table I'm trying to use doesn't exist). Since if I hit the connection error - I need to reconnect. And in any other case I need just to give error message to the user.

`SQLException.getSQLState()` always returns null and `getErrorCode()` always returns 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am no Java expert but this seems to be mainly based on Java.

You'd need to catch the exception from the `.execute()` command and query the string to see what the error is, then make a decision on which method to execute next based on that information.

Comment: 1) I don't know all possible exception messages since they are not listed (as many protocols list their error codes) so I can miss many cases
2) they can change the string in the next implementation so it will not work again

Comment: I'm sorry then I don't know what is the official solution. Maybe some Java documentation can help on your method?